# input type file open file dialog twice in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I use an input tag with type file instead of a button tag to upload image and then use NgxImageCompressService to compress it. The process is fine but the file dialog keeps opening twice every time I click the button. I've tried using stopPropagation() and preventDefault() but still got the issue.

Here's my code in html

```
        <label
          for="selectFile"
        >
          Select File
        </label>
        <input
          type="file"
          id="selectFile"
          accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg"
          (change)="uploadFile()"
          style="display: none"
        />
```

And here's my code in the component

```
  constructor(
    private ngxImageCompressService: NgxImageCompressService
  ) {}

  uploadFile() {
    const MAX_MEGABYTE = 1;
    this.ngxImageCompressService
      .uploadAndGetImageWithMaxSize(MAX_MEGABYTE, true)
      .then(
        (result: string) => {
          // some code
        },
        (result: string) => {
          // some code
        }
      );
  }
```

I tried to debug, the first time it opened the file dialog, the uploadFile() function is invoked, but the ngxImageCompressService isn't. The service is working after the second time the file dialog opened. Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: What is the problem? The file dialog is opening twice OR image service not called on first open?

Comment: both, the dialog is opening twice and on the first open the image service is not called

Comment: I am not able to replicate. Is this specific to any browser? Are there any other input file elements (hidden maybe) on the page. Any elements with duplicate id. Can you inspect and debug?

Comment: I tried in Chrome & Edge and got the same result. There aren't any other input file elements or elements with duplicate id. My assumption is maybe it's because of the function uploadAndGetImageWithMaxSize() in NgxImageCompressService library that calls the File dialog, that's why it opened twice, first from the input file tag and the second from that function.